# How to return a value and a reference to a portion of that value?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to use [some xcb bindings](https://rtbo.github.io/rust-xcb/xcb/index.html) while trying to learn Rust.

`conn.get_setup()` only borrows an immutable reference; doesn't that borrow end after the function call ends?

```rust
use std::error::Error; 
use std::convert::From;

pub struct State<'a> {
    conn: xcb::Connection,
    screen: xcb::Screen<'a>,
}

impl<'a> State<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Result<State<'a>, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let (conn, _) = xcb::Connection::connect(None)?;
        let screen = conn.get_setup().roots().next().ok_or::<Box<dyn Error>>(From::from("Couldn't get screen"))?;
        Ok(State{conn: conn, screen:screen})
    }
}
```

The compiler gives me

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `conn`
  --> /.../src/lib.rs:16:4
   |
15 |             let screen = conn.get_setup().roots().next().ok_or::<Box<dyn Error>>(From::from("Couldn't get screen"))?;
   |                          ---- `conn` is borrowed here
16 |             Ok(State{conn: conn, screen:screen})
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `conn` because it is borrowed
  --> /.../src/lib.rs:16:19
   |
12 |     impl<'a> State<'a> {
   |          -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
15 |             let screen = conn.get_setup().roots().next().ok_or::<Box<dyn Error>>(From::from("Couldn't get screen"))?;
   |                          ---- borrow of `conn` occurs here
16 |             Ok(State{conn: conn, screen:screen})
   |             ---------------^^^^-----------------
   |             |              |
   |             |              move out of `conn` occurs here
   |             returning this value requires that `conn` is borrowed for `'a`
```

Is there any way to return both `conn` and `state` or am I just limited to `conn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be a use after free error if you did this:

1. `conn` is created, it has no attached lifetime
2. We borrow `conn` for `'a`, which in and of itself is impossible since I could say the [following](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d4968ad190dd21fbde3c2f40f7275d48):

```
State::<'static>::new()
```

3. We move `conn` out of the function, invalidating any references to it.

So therefore, unless if there's a different way to achieve this in the library you're working with, this won't work as-is. Another name for this is a self-referential struct, so you might want to do some looking into why that doesn't work in rust.